# UMA model for multiple R instances

Tags: r

I have a question, maybe it's strange.
So, for example, I've got N running R terminals. I execute same code in each. So, I need to have same memory area which can be used by all terminals and where I can store shared variables for all terminals. If there is only all memory shared - it's also good solution for me.
Is it possible?

For example, let's have 2 R consoles working in parallel.

1st console code:

```
a <- 5;
b <- 6;
```

2nd console code:

```
c <- 7;
d <- 8;
```

Best variant is to have .GlobalEnv consists of a, b, c, d in both R console.
So, does R contain any package, which allow me to write something like that (pseudocode):

1st console

```
valNames <- ls(globalenv());
sapply(1:length(valNames), function(i) assign.UMAMemory(valNames[i], get(valNames[i]));
```

2nd console

```
valNames <- ls(globalenv());
sapply(1:length(valNames), function(i) assign.UMAMemory(valNames[i], get(valNames[i]));
```

after that I'll have a, b, c, d in UMAMemory.

If I need to add variables to same console environment, I can write code like this is this console:

```
totalNames <- names(UMAMemory);
sapply(1:length(totalNames), function(i) assign(totalNames[i], get.UMAMemory(totalNames[i]));
```

Yes, it's also need the same barrier mechanism for exclude writing collisions.

Comment: question reopened. Thanks for the edits

Comment: I found acceptable solution by using Rshare package.